# Is there a multilanguage program that will generate emacs-compatible who-calls information?

Tags: emacs, navigation

There is, and has been for awhile, the excellent etags program.  For many languages it allows one to generate a TAGS file which emacs can use to jump from a call site to the definition.  The versions of etags I have seen support literally oodles of languages.

Is there a similar program that can generate who-calls data?

For example, given a function foo, I'd like to generate an emacs buffer containing a list of functions which call foo.  It would be great if it supported multiple languages, although I'm primarily thinking about C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cscope hasn't been mentioned. Although it does not support multiple languages, it supports who-calls queries and integrates with Emacs.

http://cscope.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) makes call graphs, and I suppose you could take the data used for graphing and make use of it in Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

GNU global is a nice replacement for etags.

[http://www.gnu.org/software/global/][1]
http://www.gnu.org/software/global/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about anything that does this, but M-x grep works pretty well for me.  While it may generate false positives, I find that it usually works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

[CEDET](http://cedet.sf.net) can provide this information, but doesn't have ready to use tool.  You can look to the code of COGRE package, that is included into CEDET and used to build UML diagrams, including generation of diagrams from existing code